# Is it possible to send data from one form to multiple models in django using a normal form instead of multiple ModelForm?

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I know it sounds weird, but I'm struggling a lot to show multiple tables with an inline, which populates three models with foreign keys, so I'm trying to find easier solutions than creating a script with JavaScript (which I don't know how to do) or a very complicated solution. My idea is to create a normal form with all of the fields and use it to fill all the models.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created",)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("sales:order-update", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return "Order {}".format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="order_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity


class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Mexico")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("sales:modalcustomercreation")
```

```
I only tried the first solution in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720287/django-how-to-make-a-form-for-a-models-foreign-keys)  but It doesn't worked.
```

Comment: Take a loot at [django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.